# Can not display the success message after submit data using angular.js and php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

i am unable to display the success message after submit the data using Angular.js and PHP. i am using alert prompt to display the message but it is showing me the output as `undefined`.I am explaining my code below.

> createSubjectData.php:

```
<?php
$course_name=stripslashes($_POST['course_name']);
$sub_name=stripslashes($_POST['sub_name']);
$semester=stripslashes($_POST['semester']);
$sub_short_name=stripslashes($_POST['sub_short_name']);
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '******');
mysql_select_db('go_fasto', $con);
 $qry ='INSERT INTO db_subject (subject_name,short_name,semester,course_name) values ("' . $sub_name . '","' . $sub_short_name . '","' . $semester . '","' .$course_name . '")';
$qry_res = mysql_query($qry);
if ($qry_res){
        $result['msg'] = "subject has added successfully";
    } else {
         $result['msg'] =  "subject could not added ";
    }
$query='SELECT * from db_subject order by subject_id desc';
$res=mysql_query($query);
$result=mysql_fetch_array($res);
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

my controller code is given below.

```
var subjectData={'course_name':$scope.courseName.value,'semester':$scope.semester.value,'sub_short_name':$scope.subject_short_name,'sub_name':$scope.subjectname};
                console.log('subject',subjectData)
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: "php/subject/createSubjectData.php",
                    data: subjectData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        $scope.$apply(function(){
                        alert(response.msg);
                        $scope.courseName=null;
                        $scope.semester=null;
                        $scope.subject_short_name=null;
                        $scope.subjectname=null;
                        //$scope.subjectData.push(response);
                        $scope.subjectData.unshift(response);
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(response){
                        alert(response.msg);
                    }
                })
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I've always wondered, why are you using jQuery's `$.ajax()`. You do realize you can use Angular's `$http` right?

Comment: Yes, i know that but it is my just demo code.I used this only for test.Can you help me in this case

Comment: Well you get undefined because `response.msg` doesn't exist.

Comment: check my php file i am passing the message and it will return to success message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely overwriting your `$result` variable in this line

```
$result=mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

*after* you've set `$result['msg']="..."` so the msg gets lost.

**BTW:**
You've got an SQL-Injection Issue in your code. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to sanitize your input variables before adding them to your Query-string or user [mysql prepared statements `mysqli_stmt`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php)